# Problem based on Laplace and Poisson's Equations. How to find the charge from electric field and potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

[image]

[image]

In the above problem, I have found out the potential and the electric field in the medium between the two conductors. From here, how can I calculate the approximate charge per plate?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the fact that across a charged surface, the discontinuity of the normal component of the electric field is equal to $\sigma/\varepsilon_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Surface charge density $\sigma$ on the plate is related to the electric field E near the plate by the following relation
$$
\sigma = \varepsilon_r\varepsilon_0 E
$$
Hence the charge per plate is
$$
Q = h\varepsilon_r\varepsilon_0\int_r^R E(\rho)d\rho,
$$
where $h = 5$ m, $E(\rho)$ can be found from your formulas, $r = 0.002/\sin(\pi/8)$ m from the given conditions and $R = 1 + r$ m.